# SQL FORMAT function returns incorrect/old currency symbol

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019, currency-formatting

I'm using FORMAT function to show number in local currency but it returns wrong (old, depreciated) currency.

I'm using ...

```
SELECT FORMAT(1, 'C', 'hr-HR')
```

It returns ...

```
1,00 kn
```

It should return ...

```
1,00 €
```

As Croatia (hr-HR) changed currency to EUR from 2023-01-01.

Environment: SQL 2019 Std, Windows Srv 2016 Std.

How can I get the right value through FORMAT function?

Comment: OR,
You can simply format it as `SELECT FORMAT(1, '0.00 "€"', 'hr-HR');`

Let me know, if it works

Comment: Honestly, formatting should be done in your presentation layer. I hope you aren't expecting the instance to see a monetary value with another column denoting a date prior to `2023-01-01` and you get kn instead of €.  According to my Google-Fu HRK and EUR aren't a 1-to-1 conversion.

Comment: As suggested above, what is your expectation when returning monetary data that *is* for a period of time prior to 2023? Or spans both date ranges? How, or why, would the SQL Server engine or related library know? You should retrieve the numerical value from the database and format it according to your own business rules.

Comment: My expectation is just to show current, at this moment, country currency, I managed currency amount conversion.

Comment: `FORMAT` invokes .Net, as it's a CLR function, so *if* it's not producing the "correct" value, then either the lastest version of .net isn't aware of the currency change, or you aren't using the latest version of it. As @Tushar  suggest, update the version of .Net (on the host, *not* the client) first, and then retest to see if you get the same behaviour.

Comment: First, don't try to format currencies in the database. That's simply a bad idea. Second, don't just assume what the currency is based on the country, *precisely* because Croatia changed currencies. Store the currency explicitly in a separate field. Third, if you haven't updated your SQL Server, it won't know that the currency has changed. Updating the client is a lot easier than updating the database, which is one more reason  to format money on the client, not the server

Answer (score 1):

As we discussed in comments;

Your .Net version might not be up-to-date with latest currency changes.

> Either your version of .net isn't aware of the currency change, or you aren't using the latest version of it.

You can try updating your .NET Framework on the host and retest the behavior.

If it is not possible;

You can simply format it as `SELECT FORMAT(1, '0.00 "€"', 'hr-HR');`

Update :

> with the latest .NET 4.8 for WinSrv 2016 still the same problem

Can you format it like this :

```
SELECT FORMAT(1, CONCAT('N', CHAR(8364)), 'hr-HR');
```

8364 is unicode symbol for Euro.

Comment: Isn't FORMAT function "bound" to specific .Net version? So it should be whole server that should be upgraded

Comment: Assuming the currency based on locale is a major bug to begin with. Croatia changing to EUR is one reason `FORMAT` shouldn't be used - old values are not in EUR, so why should they be formatted this way?

Comment: Even in dbfiddle sql 2022 it returns "wrong" value. I Agree with your sentiment though @PanagiotisKanavos , never trust built-in regional data

Comment: I meant it ironically as it was wrong according to the OP, that's why i added in quotes.

Comment: I'm on the latest of .NET 4 and my SQL Server 2016 returns incorrect data. Sounds like .NET has not been updated.

Comment: with the latest .NET 4.8 for WinSrv 2016 still the same problem

Comment: @hoggar : Can you try this `SELECT FORMAT(1, CONCAT('N', CHAR(8364)), 'hr-HR')`

Comment: 8364 is unicode symbol for Euro